# How to get changes from branch pushed to master on local branch as uncommitted changes?

Tags: git, github

I have a branch which I had already pushed to master on remote and now I have to get those changes to a local branch and when I do cherry-pick then those changes don't show in "git status". But I want those changes to be listed out under git status command. How do I do that?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to apply those changes to your working copy, but not to commit them?

Comment: I will be committing but later. I have some changes in my local branch with which I want to combine the changes from remote branch.

Comment: It sounds like the changes exist in another local branch. Is that correct?

Comment: let me put in this way, there is a commit in remote branch R and I created a local branch X. Now I want the changes of R into X. One way is to manually copy-paste changes from R but there are many files. I can't cherry pick because it would not make the changes of R in X as uncommitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`-n` / `--no-commit` option to `git cherry-pick`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick#_options):

> `-n`
> `--no-commit`
>
> Usually the command automatically creates a sequence of commits. This flag applies the changes necessary to cherry-pick each named commit to your working tree and the index, without making any commit. In addition, when this option is used, your index does not have to match the HEAD commit. The cherry-pick is done against the beginning state of your index.
>
> This is useful when cherry-picking more than one commits' effect to your index in a row.